# Is Wi-Fi Protected Setup still safe?

Tags: wifi

According to this paper it is cracked: http://sviehb.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/viehboeck_wps.pdf

Using Reaver.

Comment: This has been a known vulnerability for quite a long time now; your question doesn't really ask anything - in direct answer, no, WPS setups are not particularly secure or safe.

Comment: You ask and answer your own question. A simple google search shows your answer. Is there something else that you are getting at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the vulnerability reaver exploits is only in kind of authentication (PIN) the question should probably be rephrased to: Is WPS broken completely or only in parts.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer - no.

If you read that paper you linked to, it details the problem.

It hasn't been safe for a long time.

Comment: What do you mean not safe for a long time? any older proof of concepts?

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified - the paper you linked to made the issue public months ago.